# the facebook app domains format error

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication

i have a web site,

which is very basic. (www.mychecktest.com) 
but i couldnt configure the facebook login integration.

for some users i try facebook integration i m getting the following error.

```
 Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: 
 One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. 
 It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

but some users can easily login with facebook. i dont know why

the following picture is my app settings page  and 
what exactly should i write to app domains. or sthng else is wrong? whatever i tried so many things. but i couldnt achieve.

[image]

Comment: did you try with mychecktest.com only?

Comment: yas i tried. i m getting error for some users, but i do not get error for some other users :S i dont know why